How make multiple Threads send same ArrayList
Hi guys I have problem with my server code for puns game, I am trying to make server send actual list of players when player join game, but server send only first list it get,
Player class:
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Player implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
    private String name;
    private Boolean isReady = false;
    private int score = 0;

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
}




Server class
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Server {
    private List<ClientHandler> clients = new ArrayList<>();
    private  List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<>(); // Corrected declaration

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server().start(12345);
    }

    public void start(int port) {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
            System.out.println("Server started on port " + port);
            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("New client connected: " + clientSocket);
                ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(clientSocket, this, playerList);
                clients.add(clientHandler);
                new Thread(clientHandler).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void broadcastPlayerList() {
        for (ClientHandler client : clients) {
            try {
                client.sendPlayerList(playerList);
                System.out.println(playerList);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public void addPlayer(Player player) {
        playerList.add(player);
        broadcastPlayerList();
    }
}


ClientHandler Class
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.List;

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private List<Player> playerList;
    private Server server;

    public ClientHandler(Socket socket, Server server, List<Player> playerList) throws IOException {
        this.clientSocket = socket;
        this.playerList = playerList;
        this.server = server;
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Object obj = in.readObject();
                if (obj instanceof Player) {
                    Player player = (Player) obj;
                    server.addPlayer(player);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendPlayerList(List<Player> players) throws IOException {
        out.writeObject(players);
        out.flush();
    }
}

I spend a lot of time on chat gpt and google search to find solution and i couldnt find one working, I am sure that this server is receiving players correctly, but idk why it doesnt send them properly. Thanks for all tips

I'm wondering if you could get easier/faster results by using existing code, such as http://www.jgroups.org/

@queeg - I expect that this is a class assignment (or self learning exercise) where using an off-the-shelf solution is self-defeating.

My first thought would be to change the workflow to use a producer/consumer concept instead.  This would have the "broadcast" service waiting on a queue, when a client adds a new player to the queue, the "broadcast" service would then be notified/unlocked when a new player is registered and it could then handle the update within it's own context.  Alternatively, you might make use of a Vector which is synchronised by default or mark the ArrayList as volatile

You need to use ObjectOutputStream.reset(). Look it up.

What does your client do? After you connect to the server you will need to then send the Player information to the server. The server will then need to broadcast the PlayerList back to all clients.

Is that duplicate the same situation? Seems to me the duplicate is attempting to send the same object twice to the same output stream. This is attempting to send the PlayerList to multiple clients and each will have a different output stream?
